# openni_camera glibc error

Tags: kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS on Ubuntu 10.04, and the command "roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch" has suddenly started to give me an error. Is there a way to fix this?

```
robot@peoplebot2:~$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
... logging to /home/robot/.ros/log/7354f21c-a317-11e0-8aa3-a088b4402bbc/roslaunch-peoplebot2-1665.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://peoplebot2:50030/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_node1/use_indices
 * /openni_node1/depth_registration
 * /openni_node1/image_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_mode
 * /openni_node1/debayering
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_node1/projector_depth_baseline
 * /openni_node1/rgb_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_translation
 * /openni_node1/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/image_mode
 * /openni_node1/shift_offset
 * /openni_node1/device_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_rotation

NODES
  /
    openni_node1 (openni_camera/openni_node)
    kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [1679]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 7354f21c-a317-11e0-8aa3-a088b4402bbc
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [1692]
started core service [/rosout]
process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [1695]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [1696]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [1697]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [1698]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [1699]
/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/bin/openni_node: /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.12' not found (required by /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so)
[openni_node1-2] process has died [pid 1695, exit code 1].
log files: /home/robot/.ros/log/7354f21c-a317-11e0-8aa3-a088b4402bbc/openni_node1-2*.log
```

---

I have followed dornhege's advice from the comments in the answer by fergs. When I only use the command "roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch", it runs correctly. However, when I try to use other packages that require the openni_camera, such as rviz or openni_tracker, [this new error occurs](http://answers.ros.org/question/1566/openni_camera-error-bad-parameter). Does anyone have an idea for fixing it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10447/openni_camera-glibc-error/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lucid (10.04) uses GLIBC 2.11, so lucid packages should not be linked against 2.12. Are you sure that you selected the right repository when you did step 1.2 of [installation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu)? I would guess that you might have typed "maverick" instead of "lucid" thus installing packages that use GLIBC 2.12.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-14**:
@qdocehf I would suggest removing the second question and making a separate posting for it.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-07**:
Do you have any ideas for fixing this new error? I have edited my question to include the new problem.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-07**:
Can your try running apt-get update, apt-get upgrade and eventually apt-get --reinstall install openni-dev. That should get you up to date to the current lucid packages.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-06**:
ros-diamondback-openni-kinect:
Installed: 0.2.1-s1306611764~lucid
Candidate: 0.2.1-s1306611764~lucid
Version table:
*** 0.2.1-s1306611764~lucid 0
500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-06**:
To verify, what does: apt-cache policy ros-diamondback-openni-kinect give you?

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-06**:
Yes, I definitely used the lucid installation. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, so I don't think that could be the problem.